# Index spool after created PK and index?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query. It runs slow but get some value when there is not a PK on `hugeTable`. The estimated execution plan shows half of the cost is "RID Lookup (Heap) [hugeTable] 51%".

I added a PK on `hugeTable` and created an index cover all the columns for the subquery of pivot. Then 80% of the cost is "Index Spool (Eager Spool)" on the cover index. (It did Index scan first (4%)).

How to avoid the "Index spool" on the hugeTable?

```
select ..., [...], [...], ...
from ....
    T1 ...
    outer apply (
        select k1, k2, [...], [...], ...
        from (
            select k1, k2, col, value
            from hugeTable 
            where k1 = T1.K1 and k2 = T1.K2
            ) p pivot (sum(value) for col in ([...], [...], ...)) as pvt
        ) a pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the index spool is likely because you are doing an outer apply.  The query optimizer knows it's going to hit every row in the subquery throughout the apply so the optimizer drops the result set into tempdb.  This is a guess, not having the actual query plan at hand.

A large percentage of your query cost is always going to be allocated somewhere.  In other words, there is no such thing as a zero cost query.  The trick here is can you improve the performance of that index spooling operation (the largest cost operation) with something else.  In the case of an outer apply... maybe not.

I would recommend re-asking this question on dba.stackexchange.com and providing the actual xml plan.  You'd likely get a much more thorough analysis that way.  You may find that in this scenario eager spool is your best option.

Also, you might try using an index hint **as a test** to see if you can force usage of an alternate plan.  Then you could actually compare performance of one plan to the other.  I rarely recommend an index hint for anything other than testing.  If you find it actually is faster I'd still research why the optimizer isn't using it.

Also make sure your stats and cache are clean and up to date and fresh for each round of testing.